# InDesign Text Frame Flow Issue

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am hoping someone may be able to assist with this problem. I am trying to fill the text frames with copy. However, as can be seen in the image, some lines are not cooperating with me. There is no formatting on the text whatsoever as it is a straight copy and paste from Notepad with no line breaks.

The text flows fine down the three rows of containers, but I cannot figure out why it is skipping lines in the last container of each row when there is clearly space for the words to fit. All the copy is present, it is just not filling the containers fully.

I have tried in both single line and paragraph composer, single and multiple columns, GREP find and replace, and pretty much everything else I could find, but nothing seems to be working. If I flow the text from frame to frame, then all the frames fill correctly with no gaps, however, I need the text to flow from row to row otherwise it does not read right. It must read like a book across the rows and down. Would anyone here have any clue as to what the problem could be?

[image: Project Image]

Comment: I think there's no solution in InDesign, it's a perfect question to ask in [Indesign Forum](https://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign)

Answer (score 5):

Indesign doesn't handle this kind of situation very well... (euphemism...)
I would do it in Illustrator instead.

Example using pathfinder & text wrap:

[image]